# "the Dart compiler exited unexpectedly." Error while working application stopped by developer

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I’m getting this error (“the Dart compiler exited unexpectedly.”) every time, and as soon as I “stop” Flutter mobile application in Android or iOS emulators in Adroid Studio. The application is working (or seems working) normally.

When I open it in Xcode (open Runner.xcworkspace) or Android Studio (android module) and run, no error returns. It is only while running from flutter environment.

Any help or idea will ve helpful for me, thanks in advance.

```
* Flutter Doctor Summary
    * Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.9, on macOS 14.2.1 23 C71 darwin-arm64)
    * Dart version 3.2.6
    * DevTools version 2.28.5
    * Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
    * Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.7+0-17.0.7b1000.6-10550314)
    * Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.2)
    * CocoaPods version 1.14.3

* Android Studio Hedgehog 2023.1.1 Patch 2
    * Flutter plugin 77.1.2 (not the latest version)
    * Dart plugin 231.94.11 (not the latest version)

Tools > SDK Manager > SDK Platforms
    * Android 13 Tiramisu - Partially installed
    * Android 12L (Sv2) - installed 
    * Android 12 (S) - partially installed 
    * Android 10 Q - partially installed

Tools > SDK Manager > SDK Tools
    * Android SDK Build-Tools 34
        * 34.0.0
        * 33.0.2
        * 32.1.0-rc1
        * 32.0.0
        * 30.0.3
    * NDK (Side by side)
        * 26.1.10909125 installed
        * 23.1.7779620 installed
    * Android SDK Command Line Tools 12.0 (latest)
    * Android Emulator 33.1.24
    * Android SDK Platform Tools 34.0.5

* pubspec.yaml
    * environment : sdk: '>=3.2.6 <4.0.0' 

* android/app/build.gradle (I didn’t change anything manually it comes from default values below)
    * targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion 
    * compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    * minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
    * ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

* <flutter root>/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/src/main/groovy/flutter.groovy
    * targetSdkVersion  = 19 (I'll use 34 - latest)
    * compileSdkVersion = 33 (I'll use 34 - latest)
    * minSdkVersion = 19 (I'll use 26)
    * ndkVersion = 23.1.7779620 (I'll use 26.1.10909125 - latest)

* AGP Upgrade Assistant
    * Brand new projects starts with 7.3.0, then AGP Assistant upgrades it to 8.2
```

Comment: can you try `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get`?

Comment: for many times, also for my old projects and brand new projects. Also I deleted android/ios folders and rebuild it, cleaned all caches, invalidate Android Studio cache and restarted it, pub clean/pub upgrade.I did everything that I read on internet.